# rpy2 vector issue with 'ListSexpVector' - Any ideas on how to fix?

Tags: python, rpy2

**tl;dr - any ideas of how to fix `AttributeError: 'ListSexpVector' object has no attribute 'items'`**

Here's the full code. The imports for `rpy2` may be different slightly for you:

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources" 

import rpy2 
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri, r, numpy2ri 
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

pandas2ri.activate()
numpy2ri.activate()
```

Then I make a test dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'status': ['treatment','treatment','control','control'], 
        'result': [20,21,19,18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then I run the first test code, and it works.

```
with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter + numpy2ri.converter): 
   r.assign("pydf", df) 
   hellow_world = r("""
          summary(pydf)        
              """) 
   print(hellow_world)
```

I get the proper R print out.
Woot. :)

But then when I try what I really want to do:

```
with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter + numpy2ri.converter): 
    r.assign("pydf", df) 
    hellow_world = r("""
          t.test(result ~ status, data = pydf)       
          """) 
    print(hellow_world)
```

I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'ListSexpVector' object has no attribute 'items'`

It seems to have to do with the `rpy2py` method, but any thoughts on how to fix would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you. The Lord Always Delivers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you encountered a bug in the `numpy2ri` submodule. The issue you're encountering is that the local converter thinks `hellow_world` is `ListSexpVector` but it appears to be `StrSexpVector` object instead (based on my quick debugging). I don't know enough about `numpy2ri` module yet to know exactly how this is happening, but here is a workaround:

**If you just want to print the R message**

```py
r.assign("pydf", df) 
hellow_world = r("""
    t.test(result ~ status, data = pydf)       
    """) 
print(hellow_world)
```

You don't need a converter at all.

**If you want to parse R message in Python**

```py
r.assign("pydf", df) 
hellow_world = r("""
    t.test(result ~ status, data = pydf)       
    """) 
with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter + numpy2ri.converter): 
    print(list(hellow_world))
```

Without the `localconverter` context `hellow_world = r(...` line returns a raw R object without triggering the erroneous conversion. Then, converting `hellow_world` to a Python list within the conversion context will trigger functional per-list-item conversions. The resulting list is a lot harder to read, but it is a Python list with str and numpy objects.

Comment: Thanks so much, @kesh, I've just ported this over to the official `ryp2` repo, to make them aware of the glitch -> https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/890